# Rollup query having joins and calculations on column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have my rollup query

```
  Select   
      CASE 
         WHEN (GROUPING(p. product_name ) = 1) THEN 'Total'
         ELSE p. product_name END AS ProductName,
  (( o.item_price - o.discount_amount )*  o.quantity) as Total_Amount  

  from 
      products as p
  inner join 
      order_items as o on o.product_id  = p.product_id
  group by  
      p.product_name, (( o.item_price - o.discount_amount )* o.quantity) with rollup
```

It return last row NULL value doesnot give total kindly solve this why i am getting total null

Actualy i am getting records using join and calculations like itemprice minus discount and multiply by quantity now apply ROLLUP on calculation feild

Comment: Can you add some sample records and a expected output?  We don't have access to your table, so we need this information to receate the conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an aggregation function in the `select`:

```
Select (CASE WHEN (GROUPING(p. product_name ) = 1) THEN 'Total'
             ELSE p.product_name
        END) AS ProductName,
      sum((o.item_price - o.discount_amount )*o.quantity) as Total_Amount  
from products p inner join 
     order_items o
     on o.product_id  = p.product_id
group by p.product_name with rollup;
```

Comment: can you tell me why we placed equal to 1 in case at first line

Comment: @GLOBALTECH . . . That is how the `GROUPING()` function works:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178544.aspx.